# Unity 3D OnCollisionEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my player jump only when they are touching the ground and to do so I made an OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) function, then I made another function called jump which makes the player jump when the space button is pressed the on the CollisionEnter function I call this function however this does not call the jump function, what am I doing wrong? when the player collides with the ground though it does print It's jumping as I have made a Debug.log check.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnCollisionEnter function is called only once, when your player collide the ground.
If you want to do that you have to use a "isGrounded" boolean variable which you set to true when is grounded (in OnCollisionEnter) and set to false when you press jump.
The jump control must be in the Update function.